# Quiero aplicar el estilo al botón de un grupo de botones al cual se le está haciendo clic, pero se le aplica a todos

Tags: angular

Tengo 2 **div** con la misma estructura (2 **p** y un **button**), cuando le doy click a cualquier botón "Copy" se le aplican los estilos que tengo implementado a todos los botones "Copy" y yo necesito que los estilos se le apliquen solo al botón que se le está haciendo click.

**Imagen del sitio y los botones**

[image: imagen del sitio y los botones]

**Imagen del sitio cuando clico en cualquier botón "Copy"**

[image: Imagen del sitio cuando clico en cualquier botón]

**Imagen de la plantilla**

[image: Imagen de la plantilla]

**A continuación dos imágenes del código de la clase, la segunda es continuación de la primera.**

[image: Código de la clase (imagen 1)]
[image: Código de la clase (imagen 2)]

*Muchas gracias de antemano. Me faltan muchas cosas por aprender de angular.*

Comment: Te sugiero que edites la pregunta y coloques tu código, en lugar de las imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un identificador único para cada url, puedes hacer lo siguiente

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  links = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'link 1',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'link 2',
    },
  ];
  onClick(id) {
    this.links = this.links.map((e) => {
      if (e.id === id) {
        e.text = 'Copied';
      }
      return e;
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let link of links">

  <button (click)="onClick(link.id)">
    {{link.text}}
  </button>
  
</div>
```

logrando lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-64opu2?file=src/app/app.component.html